# Is this question fit for Stack Overflow, or any other site on the network?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have the question `"I know there are no friendly classes in C#, are exists any other workarounds or solutions for such design?"`. For this question some workarounds or correcting the design will be the right answer. I can give title like `"Friendly classes C#"` and if somebody will google friendly class for the same problem he can find this question.

Usually after some research if fail I'm starting to ask my friends and go to forums. From my point of view Stack Overflow is one of the largest communities so there are more chances to get the answer, especially with bounties, but as I know Stack Overflow is not a forum and I should avoid questions like this one on Stack Overflow.

I'd like to know if questions like these are fit for Stack Overflow? Any place else I may ask them?

Comment: Also, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203616/why-does-c-sharp-not-provide-the-c-style-friend-keyword which has the only workarounds (inner or partial classes, neither of which are truly friends).  But if you can ask a question which includes 1) what you need to do 2) what you have tried and 3) why it isn't working for you, including a minimal example in code of each of these three points, then your question might be acceptable.  Just asking for "workarounds" isn't, as you have astutely observed. BTW, https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang is where you go to ask for this language feature.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The question "are there any alternatives for friend classes in C#" is a valid and decent question. Stack Overflow is the right site to ask.

And guess what: [you are not the first one asking this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/204739/993547).